# pg_connect in php return false

Tags: php

I show phpinfo() info page has pgsql enable support
But  in file php

```
$dbconn =pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=qlbv user=postgres password=123456")
 or die("can't connect db");
```

result of $dbconn is false;

I had config

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local  all        all                              md5   
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all        all        127.0.0.1/32        md5   
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all        all        ::1/128              md5   
# IPv4 internet connections:
host    all        all        0.0.0.0/0            md5 

# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses='*'
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'        # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                            # (change requires restart)
```

I setup webserver in centos
result of $dbconn is false;
Can you help me?
thanks!

Comment: You can get more information about the problem from [`pg_last_error()`](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php)

Comment: i had get info from pg_last_error() but result is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try types:

```
getsebool -a | grep ftp
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
getsebool -a | grep ftp
```